# How to use Moment.js to parse English words like "today" "tomorrow" "last friday" to JavaScript date object?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am looking for a JavaScript library which can parse English words like "today" "tomorrow" "last friday" to proper JavaScript date object.

I looked at [datejs](http://www.datejs.com), [sugarjs](http://sugarjs.com) and [momentjs](http://momentjs.com).

**date.js** hasn't been updated for long time.

**sugar.js** it's another prototype based full JS library. The date parsing part is nice but I don't need another full library.

**moment.js** seems really nice and I want to use it BUT I didn't find a way for it to parse words. **Am I wrong**?

Is there another alternative to above mentioned 3 libraries to do what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is known as "natural language parsing", and sorry - but it is not a feature offered by moment.js.

If you need this functionality, I recommend sugarjs.  You can use both sugar and moment in the same project if you like, or you can try using [sugar's own date API](http://sugarjs.com/dates).

Note, I usually recommend moment, except when natural language parsing is a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the keyword NLP.

Comment: Also known as "Natural Language Processing"  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing).

Comment: BTW I went with date.js. Even though it's "old" and hasn't been updated for long time but it works fine for my purpose. I don't like the idea of sugar which mess around with prototypes. Hopefully moment.js will support NLP soon.

Comment: At least use [DateJS:Evolved](https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/). See also [the datejs tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).

Comment: Will check it out! Thanks1